# User authentication in Flask - how to implement in functions?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am using Microsoft to authenticate users on my web app. I notice that when I am defining routes, to actually kick people back who are not signed in, I have to have the check built into each route:
Example:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

When I try to write a function to do this to re-use code, it doesn't kick people to login page when they're not authenticated. Example of bad code:

```
def enforce_login():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    enforce_login()
    return render_template('home.html')
```

I cannot use Flask-Login for this project. Does anyone have any ideas on how to better implement authentication with a function?

Thanks!

Comment: Even though you can't use Flask-Login, have you looked at how it implements the `login_required` function? It'll probably be very similar if not the same answer you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your first example, in which you `return redirect(url_for("login"))` if the user is not authenticated:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Now compare that to the second version of your `home` function:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    enforce_login()
    return render_template('home.html')
```

You've moved the `return` statement into the `enforce_login` function, so it no longer causes an early return from `home`.  Your call to `enforce_login` is effectively a no-op, and execution continues to the final `return render_template...` line.

If you want to move the authentication bits into common code, consider writing a decorator, like:

```
def enforce_login(f):
    def _enforce_login_wrapper(*args, **kargs):
        if not session.get("user"):
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return _enforce_login_wrapper
```

You could then write:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
@enforce_login
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

If you are going to be enforcing authentication for pretty much everything, you might be better off moving the authentication check into a [`before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) function.